# How to join two tables data in get_where clause in Codeigneitor

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to join two tables in get_where clause.how can i do that?currently i have following code.

```
if ($dep == "0") {
            $q = $this->db->get_where('pay', array("date" => $date));
        } else {
            $q = $this->db->get_where('pay', array("date" => $date, "dep" => $dep));
        }
```

currently its getting data from pay table.what i want to do is at same time to check "status" field is "Active" in 'emp' table.i want to join that to $q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below thing

```
 $q = $this->db->join('emp e','e.id = p.emp_id')->get_where('pay p', array("p.date" => $date,"e.status"=>"Active"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Please try the following.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pay');
$this->db->join('emp', 'emp.id = pay.empid');
$this->db->where('pay.date',$date);
$this->db->where('emp.status','active');
```

Here i am assuming that you are joining 2 tables by employee id.
If you need the excact query please provide the details of tables pay and emp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 $q = $this->db->join('emp','emp.id = pay.emp_id')->get_where('pay', array("pay.date" => $date,"emp.status"=>"Active"));
```

Comment: This answer came two hours after @Raj's answer, is unexplained, and is identical advice which the only difference being a lack of table aliases.